# Python: Unable to use modules from one package to another

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have problem to use modules from one package to another. I have tried existing solution, but unfortunately i could not resolve my issue. 
This is my directory structure

```
--asag
-----Resources
-----grader
      __init__.py  (empty)
      features.py
-----align 
      config.py
      util.py
      wordsim.py
      __init__.py (empty)
```

Now I want to import modules of **align** package inside **grader** package. So inside my features.py, I have written:

```
from ..align import *
```

But i get error:

```
  File "features.py", line 6, in <module>
  from ..align import *
  ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Can anyone tell me, what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it's a module. You should run it like

```
python -m asag.grader.features
```

See this answer for more: [How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)

Comment: I think you will also need an `__init__.py` inside asag.